# Как преобразовать массив в другой вид?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть такой массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [content] => 12
            [id] => tab-about-1
            [name] => Описание 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [content] => 13
            [id] => tab-about-2
            [name] => Описание 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [content] => 14
            [id] => tab-service
            [name] => Описание 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [content] => 15
            [id] => tab-service-1
            [name] => Описание 4
        )
)
```

Как преобразовать его в такой вид:

```
Array
(
    [about] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [content] => 12
                    [id] => tab-about-1
                    [name] => Описание 1
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [content] => 13
                    [id] => tab-about-2
                    [name] => Описание 2
                )
        )

    [service] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [content] => 14
                    [id] => tab-service
                    [name] => Описание 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [content] => 15
                    [id] => tab-service-1
                    [name] => Описание 4
                )
        )
)
```

Как понимаю, нужно отфильтровать все с использованием регулярного выражения?

Comment: Как определить где about, а где service?

Comment: по [id] => tab-about-1, [id] => tab-service и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как понимаю, нужно отфильтровать все с использованием регулярного выражения?

примерно так, да.

```
$result = [];
foreach($data as $d){
    preg_match('/tab-([^-]*)/', $d['id'], $matches);

    $key = $matches[1];

    if(!array_key_exists($key, $result)) $result[$key] = [];
    $result[$key][] = $d;
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно обойтись без регулярного выражения, например так:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    [, $id] = explode('-', $row['id']);

    if ($id) {
        $result[$id][] = $row;
    }
}
```